# code igniter active records query missing apostrophes 

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Code igniter is spitting out:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TEST, `cardNumber` = 411111........11, `cardExpiry` = 1212, `authCode` = 110200,' at line 1

UPDATE `pxpayRequest` SET `status` = 'approved', `cardName` = Visa, `cardHolder` = VISA TEST, `cardNumber` = 411111........11, `cardExpiry` = 1212, `authCode` = 110200, `dpsTxnRef` = 0000000800b51dde, `dpsMessage` = APPROVED WHERE `id` = 1
```

And, as is obvious it is due to the missing sets of `'`

Why is code igniter not putting these in properly?

Here is my code:

```
$id = $result->MerchantReference;
$cardName = $result->CardName;
$cardHolder = $result->CardHolderName;
$cardNumber = $result->CardNumber;
$cardExpiry = $result->DateExpiry;
$authCode = $result->AuthCode;
$dpsRef = $result->DpsTxnRef;
$dpsMessage = $result->ResponseText;

$this->db->set('status', 'approved')
         ->set('cardName', $cardName)
         ->set('cardHolder', $cardHolder)
         ->set('cardNumber', $cardNumber)
         ->set('cardExpiry', $cardExpiry)
         ->set('authCode', $authCode)
         ->set('dpsTxnRef', $dpsRef)
         ->set('dpsMessage', $dpsMessage)
         ->where('id', $id)
         ->update('pxpayRequest');
```

You can see the associated values by looking at the query above.

Here is the `print_r` of $result

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [valid] => 1
        )

    [Success] => 1
    [TxnType] => Purchase
    [CurrencyInput] => NZD
    [MerchantReference] => 1
    [TxnData1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [TxnData2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [TxnData3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [AuthCode] => 121132
    [CardName] => Visa
    [CardHolderName] => VISA CARD
    [CardNumber] => 411111........11
    [DateExpiry] => 1212
    [ClientInfo] => 125.236.220.238
    [TxnId] => 4ddd9aa1dd14c
    [EmailAddress] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [DpsTxnRef] => 0000000800b5d3c9
    [BillingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [DpsBillingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [AmountSettlement] => 8.00
    [CurrencySettlement] => NZD
    [DateSettlement] => 20110526
    [TxnMac] => BD43E619
    [ResponseText] => APPROVED
    [CardNumber2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [IssuerCountryId] => 0
)
```

Comment: It should be escaping, you need to do a quick debug in the DB driver's source to see what goes wrong. Set() is in /system/database/DB_active_rec.php (make sure it follows the correct flow path where $this->escape() is called on $value), and it should be calling escape() from /system/database/DB_driver.php whose job it is to add the quotes around the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite odd: on any recent CodeIgniter that should work correctly. The only thing I can think of that might be off is that the db library isn't correctly identifying your database, or those variables are somehow not being identified as strings (so no escaping is happening). What does `echo is_string($cardName);` say?

Comment: using `echo 'is: '.(is_string($cardName) ? 'true' : 'false');` I get `is: false`

Comment: doing `echo $cardName.' is: '.(is_string($cardName) ? 'true' : 'false');` i get `Visa is: false`

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's totally going to fail. Do this: `$cardName = (string)$result->CardName[0];`

Comment: Hmm, Stupid simple xml... it needs to be cast as type string: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-4587

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this - i think part of the issue is that some of the values returned by simplexml are considered objects. whatever the reason -- you have to cast the values as string before inserting. Thankfully its really simple, just add (string)

so from this

```
$cardName = $result->CardName;
```

to this

```
$cardName = (string)$result->CardName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the third parameter set to TRUE.

```
$this->db->set('cardHolder', $cardHolder, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just read a simple solution for this...

I changed  the value of var $_escape_char (system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php, line 36..

It was

```
var $_escape_char = '`';
```

Changed to

```
var $_escape_char = ' ';
```

and now it works... But i am affraid if I made any security issues..

Thanks